# Discord.py - How can I have a command invoked in an event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

So I am trying to create an event in discord.py where, whenever a user mentions/pings the bot, it will say something. The code below runs without errors, however the only way this will work is if my command prefix is in the message.

For my bot, the prefix is "/", so whenever I mention the bot with a "/" in the message it will say something. And if I decide to just mention the bot, the bot does not respond. I am pretty sure it's got something to do with the last line of code but I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mention in message.content.split():      
        await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

The code is written in Python 3.7.4.

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the bot will only process commands if it isn't mentioned.  You might want to move the `process_commands` out of the `else`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'm pretty sure I've done that before, I removed the ```else``` and the same result happened. ("/ @botname" works but "@botname" does not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone mentions a user the bot reads <@userid>. So if you want to use an on_message function you would want to include an

```
if '<@bot/user id>' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('hi')
```

You can also do something like...

```
if bot.user in message.mentions:
            await message.channel.send('hi')
```